# Finding indices of unique rows and columns in a 2D array and the minimum sum of the elements in those positions

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

i have stumbled upon a problem where i am given a 5x5 matrix in the form of a 2D array and i am supposed to find the minimum sum of 5 elements where each element should be in unique row and column and print the indices of those elements and the minimum sum.

The problem gave 3 test cases as example.

Test case 1:

```
{
{5, 4, 4, 1, 6},
{1, 3, 2, 4, 6},
{3, 2, 3, 2, 6},
{0, 4, 5, 4, 6},
(6, 6, 6, 6, 6}
};

Output: (3,0) (2,1) (1,2) (0,3) (4,4)
Minimum sum: 11
```

Test case 2:

```
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
};

Output: (0,0) (1,1) (2,2) (3,3) (4,4)
Minimum sum: 0
```

Test case 3:

```
{
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
{5, 4, 3, 2, 1},
{1, 2, 7, 4, 5},
{5, 4, 3, 2, 1},
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
};

Output: (0,0) (2,1) (4,2) (1,3) (3,4)
Minimum sum: 9
```

I would like to understand what is meant when they say unique row and column and all i can see from the test cases is that the column indices are starting from 0 and increasing by one for each pair of indices.I would like to know how to approach this problem.

Comment: @chigo14 It is easy to write the program in C++ because it has all that is required to write such a program.:)

Comment: @chigo14 What you need is to write a function that produces permutations.

Answer (score 0):

Unique row and column means that no two elements share a row or a column.

Here, I've highlighted the selected numbers.

You can see that when a number is selected, No other number in that same column is also selected.  No other number in that same row is selected.

> 5  4  4  ***1*** 6
>       1  3  ***2*** 4  6
>       3  ***2*** 3  2  6
>       ***0*** 4  5  4  6
>       6  6  6  6  ***6***

```
1 + 2 + 2 + 0 + 6 = 11
```

Comment: then how to approach the problem of finding the minimum sum?